# Programmatically control/intercept a Data Table refresh

Tags: vba, excel

**Background**

I have an extremely large [data table](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/06/data-tables-monte-carlo-simulations-in-excel-a-comprehensive-guide/) that takes up to 12 hours to run for around 1 million input scenarios on a high-end 64bit machine. *The scenarios are based on a number of discrete Excel models, that are then fed into a financial model for detailed calculations*

To improve the process, I am looking to test and compare the speeds of:

1. The current manual process
2. Using VBA to refresh the Data Table (with `Calculation`, `ScreenUpdating` etc off)
3. Running a `VBS` to refresh the Data Table in a invisible Excel instance

***So, I am looking for the best approach to programmatically manage a Data Table***

*Update: using code in (2) and (3) did not provide a benefit on testing a simple example with a workbook with a single large data table*

Rather surprisingly there seems to be very little - possibly no - direct support in VBA for Data Tables

**My current knowledge and literature search**

- QueryTable `BeforeRefresh` and `AfterRefresh` Events can be added with this [class module code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213187). Intellisense doesn't provide this as an option for Data Tables
- Individual PivotTables and QuertyTables can be accessed like so `ActiveWorkbookk.Sheets(1).QueryTables(1)`. Not so Data Tables
- Eliminating all other `Data Tables` and then running a `RefreshAll` was suggested in [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/573667-refresh-data-table-via-visual-basic-applications.html) MrExcel thread as a workaround.

The workaround is certainly do-able as I only have a single Data Table, but I'd prefer a direct approach if one exists.

**Yes, I'm sticking to Excel :)**

Please do not suggest other tools for this approach, both the input models and the overarching model that uses the data table are

- part of a well established ongoing process that will stay Excel based,
- have been professionally audited,
- have been streamlined and optimised by some experience Excel designers

I was simply curious if there was a way to tweak the process by refreshing a specific data table with code, which my initial test results above have concluded no to.

Comment: I have limited experience in this area, so this is just a suggestion. For scenario testing my colleagues use, variously, R, https://www.palisade.com/risk/, http://www.towerswatson.com/en/Services/Tools/igloo. That said, 1M scenarios is a lot, and I honestly don't know how any of these tools would perform under those conditions.

Comment: Andy, Thanks. I actually have one million discrete scenarios to run, as opposed to a monte carlo using continuous and/or discrete probabality distributions (@risk or crystall ball). These scenarios feed a financial model, which in turn outputs a number of metrics for each run

Comment: brettdj, what exactly do you want help with? How to only refresh the data table calculation without the rest of the model? Else, why not simply use `.Calculate` on the worksheet with the specific data table to initiate and time the full calculation? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @PeterAlbert I wanted to see if it was possible to do this directly.  Thx Philip for the bounty :)

Comment: `directly` meaning what? Only recalculating the data table?

Comment: Just wanted to suggest that you look into PowerPivot to get data into Excel. It should be much faster.

Comment: @brettdj - I am curious... why are you running such a massive simulation in Excel? Wouldn't this be better handled in a more direct programming language?

Comment: @roberto the scenarios are constructed from various existing Excel building blocks in a template form, which in turn are fed to an overall financial model

Comment: I know excel is perfect to do montecarlo scenarios, but for a huge model like that I dont think excel is your best option. I would go to c# or vb.net then just print your report in excel. you can also read the data from excel. or you can build your model in vba wich will be harder

Answer (score 1):

So, you are looking for the best approach to programmatically manage a Data Table.

Well, Excel 2013 does record a macro for me when I manually create a data table, it goes

```
Selection.Table ColumnInput:=Range("G4")
```

The signature is

```
Range.Table(RowInput as Range, ColumnInput as Range) as Boolean
```

which is documented in [Range.Table Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.table%28v=office.11%29.aspx). The Range.Table() function seems to always return true.

This is the only way to create data tables using VBA. But that's all there is to data tables anyway.

AFAIK there is no class or object for data tables, so there is no dt.refresh() or similar method. And there is no collection of data tables you could query. You have to refresh the sheet or recreate the table with Range.Table().

There is a [DataTable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.datatable%28v=office.11%29.aspx), but it is related to charts and has nothing to do with Range.Table().

As you mention, you should turn off the usual suspects, i.e.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Try to have as little formulas in your workbook. Remove all formulas not related to the cells you base the data table on. Remove any intermediate results. Best have one cell with one, possibly big, formula.

Example: G4 is your ColumnInput, and it contains =2*G3, with G3 containing =G1+G2,
then better put =2*(G1+G2) into G4.

You may have 6 cores in your high end machine. Divide your scenarios into 6 chunks and
have 6 Excel instances calculate them in parallel.

Comment: Thx for your comments. I am well versed in optimising Excel (check my profile) and the models themselves have already been stripped right down and thoroughly optimised using Charles William's [fast excel](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=charkes+willaim+fastexcel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uYgaU9TmGcKN8QfflICACw#channel=sb&q=charles+william+fastexcel&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1). My query was about direct exposure to refreshing data tables via code, not about creating them, or general optimisation.

Comment: I have added further clarity to my initial question.

Comment: You specifically asked for a direct api. So there is one, not much, but it may be useful to you. So there is no refresh, then create. Create will refresh. There is no penalty performancewise.